# Using IR Emitter and detector incorrectly

Tags: led, infrared

So I bought [this](http://www.radioshack.com/radioshack-infrared-led-emitter-and-detector/2760142.html#.VLngDSvF9z8) from radioshack and tried to set it up following this [tutorial](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/electronics-projects-how-to-build-a-commonemitter-.html).
The problem is, the red LED lights up and when i try to interfere with the connection, nothing happens. When I remove the black one, everything still works fine. How do I properly use these ir diodes?

Comment: Did you shield the detector side from ambient light?  Try testing the circuit in a dark room.  Ambient light (sun light, and most common house-hold bulbs) can have a lot of IR light with it.

Comment: @Nedd Just tried and it's still acting like a basic light switch.

Comment: Are you saying that when you remove the dark color LED the red LED is still lit?  Or do you mean the red LED goes off?

Comment: I assume you see the error in the schematic  R2 should be 330 ohm.

Comment: If you have a DVM measure the voltage across Q1.  If you then cover up Q1 (shade it from all light) the voltage across it should increase to near 9v.  Recheck the connection of the sensor and dark color LED, (one pin is usually longer, compare this to the spec sheet to determine the correct connection according to the schematic).

Comment: Also, that type of LED package is reasonably directional, probably somewhere between 30-120 degrees.  You need to point the round ends at each other.

Answer (score 1):

Here is all the troubleshooting voltages to get this working.

Approximate voltage checks for troubleshooting:
(With 9v coming from the battery)

Voltage across IR LED: 1.3v

Voltage across R1: 7.7v

Voltage across Q1: < 1v (w/light),  > 7v (w/o light)

Voltage across R2: > 6v (w/light),  < 1v (w/o light) - Note R2 value should be 330 ohms

Voltage across LED: 1.8v (w/light),     < 1v (w/o light)

"w/light" means that light (or IR) is reaching the face of Q1.

"w/o light" means that no light is reaching the face of Q1.  (Note that Q1 may need to be completely shielded from all light sources.)

Comment: I originally thought the same thing about R2. The larger resistance resulted in better sensitivity

Comment: Sensitivity?  Using a 33k in line with the LED might give only a very dim lighted LED, if it lights all.  Looking at the breadboard picture in the tutorial you can see that both resistors are 330 ohm, the parts list also shows 2 - 330 ohm parts.

Comment: I agree. 33k is too big to be inline with the led and the breadboard does show 330. I'm referring to sensitivity of the detector, assuming no inline led. I would recommend using a pot to find the best R2 value